# Characterize in terms of fibre

Tags: functions, notation, definition

I am not familiar with the notion "characterize" in the following context. Does this mean to redefine or?.... Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

For a function $f:X\to Y$, and y an element of Y, let $f^{-1}(y) := \{ x \in X| f(x) = y\}$. This is sometimes called the "fibre" of f over y.

Problem: characterize 1 to 1 and onto functions in terrm of the fibres

Comment: You are supposed to find a description of one-to-one and onto that uses fibres. Something along the lines of “A function is one-to-one if and only if its fibres are …”.

Comment: So will it be a theorem or a definition?

Comment: It will be a theorem that the characterization in terms of fibres is equivalent to the definition.